# using .contents() to get contents of xml node in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am parsing some xml returned from an ajax call in jquery.
This variable assignment:

```
var iso8601_time = $(channelNode).find('iso8601').contents()[0];
```

assigns the variable to:

```
"2014-02-28T18:29:55.237000+00:00"
```

And when I try to use it in a concatenation it comes out as [object Text].
In the returned xml there are no quotes around the value, and I think that might be the issue.

How do I need to change this to return:

```
2014-02-28T18:29:55.237000+00:00
```

Instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's `html()` or `text()` instead of `contents()`.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** here:

```
var iso8601_time = $(channelNode).find('iso8601').text();
```